# Laravel environment variable with React: is this a good practice?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, heroku

I have a React app which makes API requests to a Laravel backend.

My app is hosted on Heroku (I do not know if it changes something for my question).

I would like to differentiate a production and a local environment for these requests. I do it as follows.

In my "welcome.blade.php", I add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="app_env" content="<?php echo env("APP_ENV") ?>" />
```

The APP_ENV contains either "production" or "local".

In my React app, I have this script:

```
export let urlApi = (document.querySelector("[name=app_env]").content === "production" ) ?
"https://laravel-react.herokuapp.com/api"
:
"http://localhost/laravel_react/public/api"
;
```

And I import this function in each component which needs it:

```
import { urlApi } from './../findUrlApi';
// .....
return fetch(`${urlApi}/products`,{
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
      })
```

It works fine.

But my question is, is it a good practice? (I am a beginner in React).

Comment: Do you compile* your JS somehow? You can leverage cross-env or *env package out there in npm; to replace the env variables... I would not make env "variables" as real variables within JS code, but constants instead and change them while compiling.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Kyslik. I will take a look to these packages. Is there any security problem with my method ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is a good practice. Environment variables (like `APP_ENV` and API URLs) should not reside in the source code.

However, you could store them like usual in Laravel `.env` file but by prefixing the key with `MIX_`. For example: `MIX_API_URL=http://localhost`. Every `MIX_*` variables in `.env` file will be exposed to your React application. Then, you could get `MIX_API_URL` value from your React application by calling `process.env.MIX_API_URL`.

Updated Laravel `.env` file

```
...
MIX_APP_ENV=production (or local)   # Should be same as APP_ENV
MIX_API_LOCAL_URL=http://localhost/laravel_react/public/api
MIX_API_PRODUCTION_URL=https://laravel-react.herokuapp.com/api
```

In React components that need it

```
const { MIX_APP_ENV, MIX_API_LOCAL_URL, MIX_API_PRODUCTION_URL } = process.env;
const apiUrl = MIX_APP_ENV === 'local'? MIX_API_LOCAL_URL: MIX_API_PRODUCTION_URL;

return fetch(apiUrl + '/products', { ... });
```

If calling `process.env.MIX_API_URL` does not work and you are running `npm run watch`, try restarting `npm run watch` and hard reload your browser.

Reference

1. [Laravel Documentation - Compiling Assets (Mix) - Environment
   Variables](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#environment-variables)